i want to add dropdown to dynamic input fields table and assign multiple variables to the value attribute
I have this dynamic input fields table with dynamic add / remove rows and it works great,
i like to add other dropdowns and also instead of having a number in value attribute like i had before i like to make value as an object that holds multiple variable  and calculate everything to multiple results (Totals)


const 
  myTable_tBody = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')
, templateRow   = document.querySelector('#template-row')
, myTable_Total = document.querySelector('#my-table tfoot input[name="anstotal"]')
  ;
AddNewRow(); // first attempt

document.querySelector('#btn-add-row').addEventListener('click', AddNewRow);

myTable_tBody.addEventListener('input', setTotals);

myTable_tBody.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button[name="delete-row"]')) return;
  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
  setTotals();
  });

function setTotals()
  {
  let Total = 0;
  [...myTable_tBody.rows].forEach( r => 
    {
    let inTotal = r.querySelector('input[name="qty"]').valueAsNumber
                * +r.querySelector('select[name="sel"]').value;

    r.querySelector('input[name="total"]').value = inTotal;
    Total += inTotal;
    });
  myTable_Total.value = Total;
  }
  
function AddNewRow()
  {
  if (myTable_tBody.rows.length < 4)
    myTable_tBody.append( document.importNode(templateRow.content, true) );
  else
    alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");
}

function calc() {
  var pencil = 0;
  var ruler = 0;
  var highlighter = 0;
  var select_val = 0;

$("#template-row select#prod_list").each(function () {
    select_val = this.value;
    switch (select_val) {
      case "product_first_price":
        pencil += 10;
        ruler += 11;
        highlighter += 13;
       break;
      case "product_second_price":
        pencil += 14;
        ruler += 16;
        highlighter += 17;
       break;
      case "product_third_price":
        pencil += 18;
        ruler += 19;
        highlighter += 20;
       break;
      default:
        select_val += 0;
    }
  });

  $("#pencil").text(pencil);
  $("#ruler").text(ruler);
  $("#highlighter").text(highlighter);
 

}
 <button id="btn-add-row">Add new row</button>
    <table id="my-table">
      <thead> <tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th></th></tr> </thead>
      <tbody> </tbody>
      <tfoot> <tr><td colspan="3"> TOTAL = <input type="text" name="anstotal" value="0" readonly></td><td></td></tr> </tfoot>
    </table>

    <template id="template-row">
      <tr> 
        <td> <input type="number" name="qty" value="0" min="0"> </td>
        <td>
          <select id="prod_list" name="sel" >
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose a price</option>
            <option value="product_first_price">Product one</option>
            <option value="product_second_price">Product two</option>
            <option value="product_third_price">Product three</option>
          </select>      
        </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="total" value="0" readonly> </td>
        <td> <button name="delete-row">Delete</button> </td>
      </tr>
    </template>

         <td>
          <select id="prod_list" name="sel" >
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose a price</option>
            <option value="products4_prices">Product one</option>
            <option value="products5_prices">Product two</option>
            <option value="products6_prices">Product three</option>
          </select>      
        </td>

    <div class="produc_total">
            <div>
              Pencil:
              <span id="pencil" ></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              Ruler:
              <span id="ruler"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              Highlighter:
              <span id="highlighter"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



i tried to assigne a variable to the value in select option i used a switch case statement but  it doesn't seem to work. maybe there is an easier way.

The calc function never called! Also r.querySelector('select[name="sel"]').value is not a numeric value (except first option) ,so multiplying it by the quantity is meaningless. What is the exact logic for computing prices?

I know it's a mess It's basically this project that i found in codepen https://codepen.io/ramzi-bouali/pen/YzMWGex?editors=1000 and added the table with dynamic add / remove rows to calculate everything.

With a few modifications it is easy to create something like an Orders form (calculating sub-totals and grand-total automatically by selecting product and entering quantity), if this is what you want.

basically i want to combine this projects together
https://jsfiddle.net/camiramzi/1Lmk2ujt/4/   and  https://codepen.io/ramzi-bouali/pen/YzMWGex?editors=1000

Here are some modifications:

The products names and prices are defined in an array and the product dropdown populates programmatically.
Calc routine gets each product price from the products dropdown selected-value.
The delete-button.onclick, product.onchange, and quantity.oninput events defined in the template.
Read-only fields set as inert.



  // Array of product-names and product-prices
  const Products = [
    ["Pencil", 5],
    ["Ruler", 12],
    ["Pen", 7],
    ["Book", 11],
    ["Highlighter", 15]
  ];
var TBody; // orders table body
var Row; // template-row
var GrandTotal; // grand total textbox
const MaxItemsCount = 8;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  Row = document.getElementById('order-row');
  TBody = document.querySelector('#orders tbody');
  GrandTotal = document.querySelector('#grand-total');

  // populate products dropdown in template from Products Array
  var combo = Row.content.querySelector('select');
  combo.add(new Option('Choose a product', 0));
  Products.forEach(p => {
    combo.add(new Option(p[0], p[1]));
  });

  AddNewRow(); // first attempt

  document.querySelector('#btn-add-row').addEventListener('click', AddNewRow);
});

function Calc() {
  let grand_total = 0;
  [...TBody.rows].forEach(row => {
    let unit_price = field(row, 'product').value;
    let quantity = field(row, 'quantity').valueAsNumber;
    let item_total = quantity * unit_price;
    field(row, 'price').value = unit_price;
    field(row, 'total').value = item_total;
    grand_total += item_total;
  });
  GrandTotal.value = grand_total;
};

function AddNewRow() {
  if (TBody.rows.length < MaxItemsCount)
    TBody.append(document.importNode(Row.content, true));
  else
    alert(`Maximum ${MaxItemsCount} items`);
};

// returns an element from row by its name
function field(row, field_name) {
  return row.querySelector(`[name="${field_name}"]`);
};
#orders {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#orders td,
th {
  padding: 4px;
}

#orders tfoot {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

#orders tbody tr:only-child button[name="delete-row"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="orders">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product <button id="btn-add-row">+</button></th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Grand Total = </th>
      <th><input type="text" id="grand-total" value="0" readonly></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<template id="order-row">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="product" onchange="Calc();"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input inert name="price" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" oninput="Calc();">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input inert name="total" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button name="delete-row" onclick="event.target.closest('tr').remove();Calc();">-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>



